# Can i use FB iOS SDK and FB Graph API both for retrieving the FB friends List?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the Problem which i want to use the FB friends list in that app and i am enable to retrieve the fb Friends list through FB SDK ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FB SDK supports FB graph api calls via the following methods:

```
- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                   andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;

- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                     andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                   andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;

- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                     andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                 andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
                   andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;
```

Is this what you needed? If not, please be more specific.